# Can I use Zend Router without Zend structure?

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I have created a set of classes, and would like to route them using the Zend Router.

My structure follows the following pattern:

```
/php/
    /REST/
        index.php
    ClassOneService.php
    ClassTwoService.php
    ClassThreeService.php
```

I would like to have access to methods of classes (ClassOneService.php, ..., ClassNService.php) across a URL, for example:

```
class ClassOneService extends Connect {
    public function test () {
        echo 'hello';
    }
}
```

across

```
http://localhost/php/REST/classe_one/test
```

**My question is:** Can I use the system routes the Zend without converting my application format in Zend?

Would not want to use the MVC pattern nor extenders my classes to classes of Zend Controller, just route my methods with the Zend Router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Copy the Library/Zend folder over to your application path and then do:

```
require_once 'Zend/Controller/Router/Rewrite.php';
require_once 'Zend/Controller/Router/Route.php';

$rewrite = new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite();

$rewrite->addRoute(.....));
```

Comment: Ok, but what I put inside de addRoute? I tried to do this `$rewrite->addRoute('class_one', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'class_one/',
    array(
        'controller' => 'ClassOneService',
        'action' => 'test'
    )
));` but dont work, im not sure if I can use any class here, and in the doc dont any mentions to use other class out of ZendController scope.

Comment: You can set the routes with zend_route, however you will need to write your own code to manage the redirects. `foreach ($rewrite->getRoutes() as $route){ if ($route->match($path) { // matched, get route parts and redirect } }`

Comment: Thanks!! This helped me a lot! I could implement routing to my classes.